# Can't try Ubuntu via a USB drive

Tags: system-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu as a dual boot OS next to Windows 10. Thus I installed it on a USB drive and wanted to use the `try feature` beforehand. Sadly as soon as I choose this option my PC starts booting up to 15% then jumps to the Ubuntu start screen with the five dots and usually justs stops at some point and gets stuck. In some other cases I just get thrown right back to the grub menu after some time. As how to get it running, I am somewhat unsure. Any suggestions are appreciated.

I tried it with the Ubuntu LTS version as well Ubuntu 15.10 version and failed both times. I'm doing it on a Schenker XMG A704 laptop, if that's any help. If you need some error messages or something in order to help me out, please let me know how to create these, since every-time this happens I just get thrown back to the menu as if nothing happened or I have to soft reset my laptop in order to boot again.. I am happy to provide any details needed

Thanks in advance,
John
(BTW I searched the existing questions, but didn't find something relating to this. If your search skills are better than mine, please don't hesitate to refer to your findings.)

Comment: Have you got a Nvidia graphic card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same machine - a CLEVO based SCHENKER XMG A704 - this is how it works :

First disable hibernation in Windows - open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
powercfg /h off.
```

Also disable Fast startup in Windows -> open Windows Control Panel (old version) -> Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup. In case that it is not visible, enable show hidden settings.
Shutdown the notebook completely, do NOT reboot it (otherwise it always starts Windows).

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media you created and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop - start the installation of Ubuntu.

After it is  finished, boot the installed Ubuntu system and select the Ubuntu GRUB menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system and first of all install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot the Ubuntu operating system ... now you don't have to add the parameter any more.

Note : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0` !
After having installed the Ubuntu system, you have to select Ubuntu as the default system to boot in BIOS/UEFI settings. You can select to boot Windows from the GRUB menu afterwards.

Comment: Thx very much. It worked! Installing Nvidia drivers right now